# How to get multiple selected cell in Datagridview

Tags: c#, datagridview

How can I get the coordinate / location / anything of multiple selected cells. I mean like dragging from column 1,row 1 to column 5,row 7 in a datagridview which is already populated with data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [DataGridView.SelectedCells](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.selectedcells%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property : it returns the lists of all selected cells.